# Firefox won't update view more than one time. (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, firefox, updates

I have simple web app with 3 boolean fields (checkboxes). I create database to keep their values and set that only one can be checked. If I run this on Chrome it works like charm.

For example at start I have first checkbox checked :

[image]

Then I click second one

[image]

This is proper bahavior which I get using Chrome. But when I'm using Firefox it works only on first change state then I can check all checkboxes. I checked database and inside of it I have all the time good values but firefox display wrong one.

html

```
{% for object in objects %}
                    {% if object.is_active %}
                        <input id="active" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="changee({{ object.id }})">
                    {% else %}
                        <input id="active" type="checkbox" onclick="changee({{ object.id }})">
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

views.py schedule_id is object.id I pass in html by changee function

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    objects = TimeTable.objects.all()
    if schedule_id is not None:
        schedule_value_change = TimeTable.objects.get(pk=schedule_id)
        schedule_rest = TimeTable.objects.exclude(pk=schedule_id)
        if schedule_value_change.is_active:
            schedule_value_change.is_active = False
        else:
            schedule_value_change.is_active = True
            for schedulerest in schedule_rest:
                schedulerest.is_active = False
                schedulerest.save()
        schedule_value_change.save()
        return redirect('schedule')
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Additionally I add that when I looks to logs on Chrome arter change checkbox state I get :

```
[13/Dec/2018 14:42:53] "POST /schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Dec/2018 14:42:53] "GET /schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7992
[13/Dec/2018 14:42:53] "GET /schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7992
```

But when I do it on Firefox I get

```
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "POST /schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7992
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /schedule/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7992
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /static/css/home.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /static/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /static/css/schedule.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /static/images/logout.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[13/Dec/2018 14:43:23] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2586
```

It's quite strange that all the time it get static and that lookings for favicon.ico ?

P.S On Edge it works too, only firefox is retarded

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a refresh issue. If you don’t have anything on that page that may be affected, try  coding in a dynamic page refresh/reload after click to see if that works. If anything, it’ll help you troubleshoot.

Comment: The point is that if I just refresh page by f5 it still won't work. When I do ctrl+f5 It gives me proper values. But when I change state after ctrl+f5 refresh it works properly first time. This is quite strange, for this first time it gives me same logs

Comment: firefox is taking values from cache. try this - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/905902

Comment: @VaibhavGupta still no change

Comment: @KyluAce check the requests it is making on each refresh. If it is making 1-2 GET requests, then most probably it is a cache problem

Comment: @VaibhavGupta It also get's double GETs on Chrome and it works

Comment: @KyluAce try in incognito